# Is it possible run CMD.exe as Admin -AND- Start In a different partition?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, administrator

There are **many** questions on running CMD.exe as admin on Windows 7, however none of them appear to include a different "Start In" directory / partition.

- I can start a command prompt in a different partition by setting the "Start In:" field in the short cut properties.  (ie G:\Users\Adam\Work)
- I can run the command prompt as Admin by any of the conventional methods: ctrl+alt+e, changing the short cut Advanced tab to run as admin, etc...
- I can **NOT** do them at the same time...  Setting the Start In field to G:\Users\Adam\Work and attempting to run the short cut as Admin causes a Network Error (see below)

My Current workaround to is to remove the Start In field (it then starts in C:Windows\System32) and cd into my other partition (G:\Users\Adam\Work) and type "G:" to switch drives.  Opening many cmd windows, to do SW development has become extremely annoying.  Is there a better solution than this (other than installing an external shell)?

**Network Error**
Windows cannot access C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use the [`/k`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) option to run commands at launch and keep the window open. For your example, create a shortcut with the following target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "G: & cd Users\Adam\Work"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for.  Thanks!

Comment: You may use single command: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "cd /d G:\Users\Adam\Work"`

Answer (score 2):

Use ..

```
cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\"
```

where `%V` is the full UNC to the target partition/folder.