# How to Open CMD in a folder from CMD

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to run a command from CMD, to open CMD in 'C:\Users' or some arbitrary directory. In linux I just use the parameter '--working-directory=' but in windows I can't fid a way to do it.

Also I need to do it in windows xp, vista and 7. Anyone can help?

Comment: **Related**: http://superuser.com/q/403362/100787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You may use following command in `cmd` prompt

`start cmd /k cd /d "C:\users"`

2) Or, switch to alternative console [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) (I'm the author of it) and run

`cmd "-new_console:d:C:\Users"`

Some user comments on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Does ConEmu offers extra advantages over cmd?

Comment: Yep. ConEmu offers hundreds of useful options :) Tabs, Ansi X3.64, handy text selection, quake mode, palettes, smooth resize, application distinct options, and much more.